# mat-chip select event emitter not firing?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/y4e4jS89gOxRKQOyUW2r?p=preview

I'm using the selectionChange @Output on a mat-chip to see the resulting behavior of chip selection but it seems that the eventEmitter isn't firing on chip selection?

.html:

```
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip (selectionChange)="changeSelected($event)">Papadum</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip (selectionChange)="changeSelected($event)">Naan</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip (selectionChange)="changeSelected($event)">Dal</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>

<p>Currently Selected: {{selected}}</p>
```

.ts:

```
selected: string;

changeSelected(e) {
  console.log(e);
  this.selected = e.value;
}
```

In this case, no event is emitted at all on click selection. Is this something that is still in development, or does selection mean something different from what I am thinking of?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not sure what the purpose of this component is, since it's still a work in progress, but it seems to be about providing an interface to disabling and enable selectable content, and some other features.

You're not seeing any events firing because you haven't activated selected.

In your case, something like this will resolve it.

```
  <mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip [selected]="state1" (selectionChange)="changeSelected($event)" (click)="state1=!state1">Papadum</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip [selected]="state2" (selectionChange)="changeSelected($event)" (click)="state2=!state2"> Naan</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip [selected]="state3" (selectionChange)="changeSelected($event)" (click)="state3=!state3"> Dal</mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
```

Also if you want to make this more generic, resort to `*ngFor` directive

in html

```
  <mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let chip of chips" [selected]="chip.state" (selectionChange)="changeSelected($event)" (click)="chip.state=!chip.state">{{chip.name}}</mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
```

in ts

```
  chips = [
    {name: 'Papadum'},
    {name: 'Naan'},
    {name: 'Dal'}
  ];
```

Comment: I see, I thought selection of a chip was tied to click events inherently but I guess that is not the case. Will wait to see where the development of chips go.

Comment: nice work. i like the way mat-chip is rendered but i found it difficult to implement them as an action buttons. ended like using mat-toggle-buttons inside a mat-toolbar. pity... :(

Comment: you can use `#chip="matChip"` and then `chip.select()`

Comment: Hi, @SteveDrake, just sharing that `chip.toggleSelected()` works better in my case.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a sample which I was able to use to make it working. works even if the categories are selected by default. You can also use `select()` method instead of `selectViaInteraction()` which I have used in the demo.

HTML:

```
<mat-chip-list #chipList [multiple]="true" [selectable]="true">
  <mat-chip *ngFor="let category of categories" #chip="matChip" (click)="category.selected ? chip.deselect() : chip.selectViaInteraction()" [selected]="category.selected" [selectable]="true" class="leadr-category-chip" (selectionChange)="changeSelected($event, category)">
    {{category.name}}
    <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

TS:

```
changeSelected($event, category): void {
  category.selected = $event.selected;
}
```

SAMPLE:

```
this.categories = [
  {
    name: 'Category 1',
    selected: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Category 2',
    selected: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Category 3',
    selected: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Category 4',
    selected: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Category 5',
    selected: false
  }
];
```

Comment: `chip.toggleSelected(true)` will work better since in this case ternary expression isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

The above implementation threw some errors for me.
Worked out a simple way to detect selection:

```
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip  color="primary" [selected]="vehicle._id === selected_vehicle_id" *ngFor="let vehicle of available_vehicles" (click)="selectVehicle(vehicle)">{{vehicle.number}}</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

In TS:

```
selectVehicle(v){
  this.selected_vehicle_id = v._id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default this control works with keyboard input.

To make it work with mouse click use `#chip="matChip"` and call its `select()`

eg

```
<mat-chip-list>
   <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of items" #chip="matChip"  (click)='chip.select()' (selectionChange)='changeSelected($event, segment )'>{{item}}</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working example, after a lot of search find a solution on stack overflow,

**Template file**

```
<mat-chip-list class="mat-chip-list-stacked"  aria-orientation="vertical">
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of religion" 
              [selected]="item.id === selected_religion_id" 
              (click)="selectReligion(item)">
                            {{item.name}}
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

**ts File**

```
religion: any[] = [
    {name: 'Hinduism', id: 1},
    {name: 'Islam', id: 2},
    {name: 'Skikhism', id: 3},
    {name: 'Christianity', id: 4},
    {name: 'Other', id: 5}
  ];

selected_religion_id: any;

 selectReligion(religion) {
    this.selected_religion_id=religion.id;
    console.log(religion);
  }
```