# How to extend page-object to include non-standard HTML Elements

Tags: watir, page-object-gem

I am looking for tutorials or help on how to extend the page-object gem (github.com/cheezy/page-object) to support elements like the Angular mat-chip. This element is very similar to a check box, but isn't recognized as such by page-object. The closest things Ive found are here.

https://williamjamespowell.com/2012/12/01/extending-pageobjects/

https://williamjamespowell.com/2012/12/27/gxt-pageobject-widget-example/

These examples are 8 years old and I don't know if they would still work. Unfortunately that is the extent of what Ive found on how to extend page-object functionality.

What I would like to do is create a mat-chip class and wire it up so that I could use that just like I would checkbox from page-object. I just can't quite figure out what all the pieces are that have to be wired up.

Comment: Try taking a look at the [Page-Object wiki for custom elements](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Custom-page-object-elements-by-using-widgets.). Let me know if you run into issues/questions.

Comment: out of curiosity, what additional behaviors are you looking to use from a mat-chip element?

Comment: @titusfortner, mat-chip is just a glorified checkbox, really. All I want is to have it support basic checkbox functionality like 'check, uncheck, and ischecked'. Right now the only way I can figure out if its checked is to have two definitions of the mat-chip using element(name, class, text). One using mat-chip as the class and one using mat-chip-selected. If one is present, the other isnt. This solution is less than optimal.

Comment: @JustinKo, your example uses a label to do the interaction with the hidden radio. I don't have such an element. So, I'm not sure how to even identify or locate the mat-chip. Here's what the html looks like: 
<mat-chip _ngcontent-qjf-c14="" class="mat-chip mat-primary mat-standard-chip custom-mat-chip" id="visibilityPublic" name="visibilityPublic" role="option" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" style="background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234);"> Public <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></mat-chip>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Angular person, so I stole a clickable mat-chip example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47962183/1200545. Depending on your implementation, you may need to tweak the code below.

First off, Page-Object has a limitation when defining widgets that use a custom tag name - ie "mat-chip". To get around this, we will define an associated method/locator in Watir:

```
module Watir
  module Container
    def mat_chip(*args)
      HTMLElement.new(self, extract_selector(args).merge(tag_name: "mat-chip"))
    end
    def mat_chips(*args)
      HTMLElementCollection.new(self, extract_selector(args).merge(tag_name: "mat-chip"))
    end
  end
end
```

We can then create a widget and accessors in Page-Object:

```
class MatChip < PageObject::Elements::Element
  def self.accessor_methods(widget, name)
    widget.send('define_method', "check_#{name}") do
      self.send("#{name}_element").check
    end

    widget.send('define_method', "uncheck_#{name}") do
      self.send("#{name}_element").uncheck
    end

    widget.send('define_method', "#{name}_checked?") do
      self.send("#{name}_element").checked?
    end
  end

  def set(bool = true)
    click unless set? == bool
  end
  alias check set

  def clear
    set(false)
  end
  alias uncheck clear

  def set?
    attribute_value('aria-selected') == 'true'
  end
  alias checked? set?

  PageObject.register_widget :mat_chip, self, :mat_chip
end
```

You can then use the accessor, named "mat_chip", the same was as a checkbox:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  mat_chip('mychip', index: 1)
end

page = MyPage.new(browser)
page.check_mychip
p page.mychip_checked?
#=> true
page.uncheck_mychip
p page.mychip_checked?
#=> false
```

Alternatively, you can use the mat-chip directly as a nested element:

```
page.mat_chip_element.check
p page.mat_chip_element.checked?
#=> true
page.mat_chip_element.uncheck
p page.mat_chip_element.checked?
#=> false
```

Comment: Wow...thanks, Justin. I went ahead and marked this as answered even though I haven't hooked this code up. If it doesn't work, I'm sure its my error. Thank you!

Comment: Updated: Got everything all hooked up and its working perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: I logged the issue, https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/500#issue-793622287, to provide better support for this scenario.